# How to catch error when get_headers() tries to resolve unresolvable host?

Tags: php, header, http-headers

Consider the following:

```
$url = 'http://psyng.com/u/9716602b';
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
print_r($headers);
```

Since the domain psyng.com is unresolvable, this code results in:

```
Warning: get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
No such host is known
```

And then the script stops running. Is there a way to keep the rest of the script running - in other words: to catch the error, and move forward with resolving the next URL? So something like:

```
$url = 'http://psyng.com/u/9716602b';
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
if ($headers == 'No such host is known') {
  // nevermind, just move on to the next URL in the list...
}
else {
  // resolve header stuff...
}
```

Comment: get_headers Inconsistency : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781795/get-headers-inconsistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script shouldn't stop running as the message produced is just a warning. I tested this script myself and that's the behaviour I see. You can see in [the documentation](http://ca.php.net/get_headers) that `get_headers()` will return `FALSE` on failure so your condition should actually be

```
if ($headers === FALSE) {
    // nevermind, just move on to the next URL in the list...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function get_headers returns a boolean result; the purpose of print_r is to return boolean in a human readable format.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://psyng.com/u/9716602b';
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
if ($headers === FALSE) { //Test for a boolean result.
  // nevermind, just move on to the next URL in the list...
}
else {
  // resolve header stuff...
}
?>
```